# How to receive data from server on two clients

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

I have a client-side test function, which sends a test object to a socket.io server whose job it is to wait for the client event, and then emit data to every client in the room that the original client emitted the event from. However, only the original client is receiving the event from the server. the other client in the room is not receiving it.

I've tried both `io.in(room).emit()` as well as `io.to(room).emit()` server-side. both clients definitely join the same room. and the server receives the event from the originating client, as well.

Server.js :

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const server = require("http").createServer(app);
const io = require("socket.io").listen(server);
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
io.on("connection", socket => {
    console.log("user connected: " + socket.id);
    socket.on("test", test => {
        console.log("received from client, emitting to room: " +     test.room);
        // io.to(test.room).emit("test", {key: "property from server"}
        // io.in(test.room).emit("test", {key: property from server"}
    })
})
server.listen(port, () => {
    console.log("server running on port: " + port);
});
```

Parent Component:

```
const socket = io("http://172.31.99.250:3000");
export default class Lobby extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      username: "",
      queue: [],
      playerOne: null,
      playerTwo: null,
      currentMove: "",
      matchFound: false,
      room: null
    };
  }
componentDidMount() {
  this.joinLobby();
}
joinLobby() {
  socket.emit("findMatch() )
  socket.on("matchFound", data => {
  this.setState({
    currentMove: data.currentMove,
    playerOne: data.p1,
    playerTwo: data.p2,
    matchFound: true,
    room: data.gameId
  });
});   
render() {
    return this.state.matchFound == true ? (
         <ChildComponent
             room={this.state.room}
             socket={socket}
         />
     );
}
}
```

Child Component:

```
export default class GameBoard extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      inProgress: true,
      msg: null
    }
componentDidMount() {
    alert("Room ID: " + this.props.room);
}
onTest = () => {
this.props.socket.emit("test", {
  testKey: "testProperty",
  room: this.props.room
});
this.props.socket.on("test", response => {
  alert("response received: " + response.key);
  });
};
render() {
   <View>
     <TouchableOpacity
       onPress={this.onTest}
     />
   </View>
 }
 }
```

I expect the server message to be read on both connected clients, every client in the room the original event was sent from, however only the originating client receives the server message, not the second client I the same room

Answer (score 0):

I think in server.js you need to do

```
socket.join(test.room);
```

Comment: There' s a function in the server that creates a game object with unique id and uses that id as a room name and joins socket to the room. then in a socket event, the game objects are iterated over and ultimately the second socket joins the room also